# Capital Gains from property sale in India - nonresident alien student in USA

Tags: capital-gains-tax

I inherited a property from my mother after she passed away. The property is in India and I wish to sell it and invest it in infrastructure bonds to avoid capital gains tax in India.

I am currently a student in the US on F1 visa (nonresident alien for tax purposes). I came across this IRS page: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/the-taxation-of-capital-gains-of-nonresident-alien-students-scholars-and-employees-of-foreign-governments. I am not able to decide how to interpret this:

1. A US source of capital gain will be treated as a foreign source if your tax home is not US

OR

2. Foreign capital gains will be treated as US source if US is your tax home.

The first interpretation of course means that I do not have to report this in my US tax return but the second one suggests that I should.

Which interpretation is correct?